# A question on metrizable space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples

This exercise is from "General Topology" by Engelking:

> **Give an example of a metrizable space which cannot be embedded in a locally compact metrizable space.**

I don't how to start. The counterexample cannot be $\mathbb R$ since it is locally compact. 
Also it cannot be a discrete space since it is locally compact.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You want to look at infinite-dimensional normed vector spaces.

Comment: @dc2814: Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You need a non-separable space, as all second countable $T_3$ spaces are embeddable into the Hilbert cube, which is compact metrizable. The hedgehog space with $\kappa$ many spines (as defined in Engelking) is universal for all metrizable spaces of weight (density) $\kappa$, so _if_ an example exists, it must be one of these (if we could embed the hedgehog, we could embed every space of that weight). My guess is $\kappa = \aleph_1$ should do it.

Comment: Correction to previous: the hedgehog is _not_ universal, its countable power is. So that argument does not work, but the hedgehog does: see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take any metric space $X$ that has a point $p$ such that no neighbourhood of $p$ has countable weight. E.g. the [hedgehog space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedgehog_space) with $\aleph_1$ many spikes will do (as the open ball neighbourhoods of the "fusion point" are all homeomorphic to the whole space).

If we could see $X$ as a subspace of $Y$ which is locally compact, then $p$ has a compact neighbourhood $C$ in $Y$, which must be second countable (as a metrisable compact space) and must contain a neighbourhood of $p$ in $X$ as subspace, which would give $p$ a second countable neighbourhood.

So every subspace of a locally compact metrisable space is locally second countable, is what we really use. So we just need a metrisable space that doesn't have this property.